# numpy's "linalg.eig()" and "linalg.eigh()" for the same hermitian matrix

Tags: python, matrix, eigenvector

**This question was due to a misunderstanding. See the answer below.**

numpy.linalg methods eig() and eigh() appear to return different eigenvectors for the same hermitian matrix. Here the code:

```
import numpy as np

H = [[0.6 , -1j, 0], [1j, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, -1]]

evals, evects = np.linalg.eig(H)
print('\nOutput of the eig function')
for i in range(0,3):
    print('evect for eval=',evals[i],'\n',evects[i,0],'\n',evects[i][1],'\n',evects[i][2])
    
evals, evects = np.linalg.eigh(H)
print('\nOutput of the eigh function')
for i in range(0,3):
    print('evect for eval=',evals[i],'\n',evects[i,0],'\n',evects[i][1],'\n',evects[i][2])
```

Comment: `eig` and `eigh` both give eigenvectors as columns. You're looking at rows.

Comment: Thank you. Stupid mistake of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this to help anyone who might have had the same kind of misunderstanding I had:

The eigenvectors are the **columns** of the resulting matrix for both functions. The fault was in the original code, which extracted rows from the eigenvector matrix instead of columns. The correct code is the following one.

```
H = [[0.6 , -1j, 0], [1j, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, -1]]

evals, evects = np.linalg.eig(H)
print('\nOutput of the eig function')
for i in range(0,3):
    print('evect for eval=',evals[i],'\n',evects.T[i,0],'\n',evects.T[i][1],'\n',evects.T[i][2])
    
evals, evects = np.linalg.eigh(H)
print('\nOutput of the eigh function')
for i in range(0,3):
    print('evect for eval=',evals[i],'\n',evects.T[i,0],'\n',evects.T[i][1],'\n',evects.T[i][2])
```